# Notify when the file contents are changed

Tags: file, process, file-sharing

There are two processes which will be accessing a file. Whenever, the file contents are modified in one process, I need to read the file and update something in the other process. Can you please tell me how to do this. I am not asking for code. just give the idea to do that. maybe some links, which would help me to acheive this. I saw something FindFirstChangeNotification for windows environment. I need something similar to this in linux environment

Thanks,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the python [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) package.  It provides cross platform file change monitoring, using a variety of techniques (depending on the platform).  Even if you're not using python, you can use the ideas/techniques for the language of your choice.  The watchdog page also mentions similar packages, should you be interested in further research.

Answer (score 0):

I ported some functions of Windows API to linux like (FindFirstChangeNotification, FindCloseChangeNotification) it has some limitations, but for what you need it must be enought, please take a look at: https://github.com/paulorb/FileMonitor
It is a simple implementation that could run on windows/linux with the same functions definitions.